# How to make an exception in my CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm quite new with HTML and CSS so this might be quite a rookie question, or I may have some messy code. Below is the HTML for a div of my webpage's front page;

```
<div id="header" class="hero container mainfrontimage">
            <h3>WEBSITE TITLE </h3>
            <img src="../images/Logo.png" id="headerimg">
            <div class="buttons"><a class="btn btn-alt" href="../3 Join us/joinus.html">JOIN US</a> <a href="../6 Shop/shop.html" class="btn btn-alt">SHOP</a></div>
        </div>
```

and the CSS..

```
#header {
    background: url('../images/WEBSITE TITLE pics/placeholder2.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    border-top: 4px ridge #E0CC95;
    border-bottom: 4px ridge #E0CC95;
    opacity: 0.75;
}
```

Essentially the header ID fills the div with my background image exactly as I'd like it, with the right opaqueness and styles. But, because the title, logo and buttons in the HTML are all included in this, they also become less opaque. I was wondering if there's some way of making just the image opaque with the borders etc. and have the text not be affected- like an exception.

I've tried putting the title, logo and buttons into a separate div but because the image itself is in the CSS it means the original div with id="header" is empty.. which wouldn't make a lot of sense and doesn't work either.

Sorry if this is a huge mess, I'm really new to this. If anyone somehow figures out what I'm asking and can provide a solution I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't apply background image directly to the `div`, if you want to control only the opacity background image, and not of the content. Instead, use a pseudo element like below.

```
<div id="header" class="hero container mainfrontimage">
    <h3>WEBSITE TITLE </h3>
    <img src="../images/Logo.png" id="headerimg">
    <div class="buttons"><a class="btn btn-alt" href="../3 Join us/joinus.html">JOIN US</a> <a href="../6 Shop/shop.html" class="btn btn-alt">SHOP</a></div>
</div>

#header {
    position: relative;
    border-top: 4px ridge #E0CC95;
    border-bottom: 4px ridge #E0CC95;
}

#header::after {
    content: "";
    background: url('../images/WEBSITE TITLE pics/placeholder2.jpg') no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    opacity: 0.75;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;   
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much karthikaruna I really appreciate that! And well done on understanding my terribly worded post haha

Comment: Glad that I helped :)